# Get VAR's coefficients for old basis

Tags: pca, interpretation, model, vector-autoregression

I've made dimensionality reduction with PCA and got data expressed with new orthogonal basis PCA1, ... , PCA4.

After I've modelled VAR (Vector autoregression model) and got some coefficients for PCA1, ..., PCA4 equations. How to transform this coefficients to apply for my original data? I need these coefficients to make interpretation of my model.

I don't want to build VAR without PCA, because it give me worse predictive results.